# Symbolic simplification of algebraic expressions composed of complex numbers

Tags: python, sympy

I have a question concerning the symbolic simplification of algebraic expressions composed of complex numbers. I have executed the following Python script:

```
from sympy import *

expr1 = 3*(2 - 11*I)**Rational(1, 3)*(2 + 11*I)**Rational(2, 3)
expr2 = 3*((2 - 11*I)*(2 + 11*I))**Rational(1, 3)*(2 + 11*I)**Rational(1, 3)

print("expr1 = {0}".format(expr1))
print("expr2 = {0}\n".format(expr2))
print("simplify(expr1) = {0}".format(simplify(expr1)))
print("simplify(expr2) = {0}\n".format(simplify(expr2)))
print("expand(expr1) = {0}".format(expand(expr1)))
print("expand(expr2) = {0}\n".format(expand(expr2)))
print("expr1.equals(expr2) = {0}".format(expr1.equals(expr2)))
```

The output is:

```
expr1 = 3*(2 - 11*I)**(1/3)*(2 + 11*I)**(2/3)
expr2 = 3*((2 - 11*I)*(2 + 11*I))**(1/3)*(2 + 11*I)**(1/3)

simplify(expr1) = 3*(2 - 11*I)**(1/3)*(2 + 11*I)**(2/3)
simplify(expr2) = 15*(2 + 11*I)**(1/3)

expand(expr1) = 3*(2 - 11*I)**(1/3)*(2 + 11*I)**(2/3)
expand(expr2) = 15*(2 + 11*I)**(1/3)

expr1.equals(expr2) = True
```

My questions is why the simplifications does not work for `expr1` but
works for `expr2` thoug the expressions are algebraically equal.
What has to be done to get the same result from `simplify` for `expr1` as for `expr2`?

Thanks in advance for your replys.

Kind regards

Klaus

Answer (score 1):

You can use the minimal polynomial to place algebraic numbers into a canonical representation:

```
In [30]: x = symbols('x')

In [31]: p1 = minpoly(expr1, x, polys=True)

In [32]: p2 = minpoly(expr2, x, polys=True)

In [33]: p1
Out[33]: Poly(x**2 - 60*x + 1125, x, domain='QQ')

In [34]: p2
Out[34]: Poly(x**2 - 60*x + 1125, x, domain='QQ')

In [35]: [r for r in p1.all_roots() if p1.same_root(r, expr1)]
Out[35]: [30 + 15⋅ⅈ]

In [36]: [r for r in p2.all_roots() if p2.same_root(r, expr2)]
Out[36]: [30 + 15⋅ⅈ]
```

This method should work for *any* two expressions representing algebraic numbers through algebraic operations: either they give the precise same result or they are distinct numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It works (but nominally) for `expr1` because when the product in the radical is expanded you get the cube root of 125 which is reported as 5. But SymPy tries to be careful about putting radicals together under a common exponent, an operation that is not generally valid (e.g. `root(-1, 3)*root(-1,3) != root(1, 3)` because the principle values are used for the roots. But if you want the bases to combine under a common exponent, you can force it to happen with `powsimp`:

```py
>>> from sympy.abc import x, y
>>> from sympy import powsimp, root, solve, numer, together
>>> powsimp(root(x,3)*root(y,3), force=True)
(x*y)**(1/3)
```

But that only works if the exponents are the same:

```py
>>> powsimp(root(x,3)*root(y,3)**2, force=True)
x**(1/3)*y**(2/3)
```

As you saw, `equals` was able to show that the two expressions were the same. One way this could be done is to solve for `root(2 + 11*I, 3)` and see if any of the resulting expression are the same:

```py
>>> solve(expr1 - expr2, root(2 + 11*I,3))
[0, 5/(2 - 11*I)**(1/3)]
```

We can check the non-zero candidate:

```
>>> numer(together(_[1]-root(2+11*I,3)))
-(2 - 11*I)**(1/3)*(2 + 11*I)**(1/3) + 5
>>> powsimp(_, force=True)
5 - ((2 - 11*I)*(2 + 11*I))**(1/3)
>>> expand(_)
0
```

So we have shown (with force) that the expression was the same as that for which we solved.  (And, as Oscar showed while I was writing this, `minpoly` is a nice candidate when it works: e.g. `minpoly(expr1-expr2) -> x` which means `expr1 == expr2`.)

Comment: If I excute powsimp(expr1, force=True), where expr1 = 3*(2 - 11*I)**Rational(1, 3)*(2 + 11*I)**Rational(2, 3) it does not work I get the result 3*(2 - 11*I)**(1/3)*(2 + 11*I)**(2/3).

Comment: Yes, it "only works if the exponents are the same". So if you want to patch around the current behavior you have to process radicals with the same denominator in the exponent so they also have the same exponent, join them under a common radical, and then expand them, e.g. `r = root(2+11*I,3);powsimp(expr1.subs(r**2,y*r),force=1).expand().subs(y,r) -> 2*root(2+11*I,3)`